# You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI [WINDOWS]

Tags: python, django

Hi guys I'm getting this error and I don't know how to fix this

the command that I run in my console is the following:

> pip install -r ..\requirements\local.txt

```
    It appears you are missing some prerequisite to build the package from source.

    You may install a binary package by installing 'psycopg2-binary' from PyPI.
    If you want to install psycopg2 from source, please install the packages
    required for the build and try again.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).

    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
```

I don't know how to fix this I really need help

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do.  https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2-binary/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like it says, try installing psycopg2-binary instead of psycopg2 - which will be installed from source, like all pip packages, and require build tools to be present. I never used pip/python on Windows, but psycopg2 is kinda notorious for build errors, so I myself resorted to binary recently - everything else just builds from source on my Mac and Linux boxes, except for psycopg2.
It looks like you will need to modify the requirements file accordingly.